# What exactly does transaction.state.log.min.isr mean?

Tags: apache-kafka

At all the scenarios if any one Kafka broker is up and running my producers and consumers should run properly.

The parameters inside `server.properties` are below for High availability of cluster.

```
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
```

1. If all 3 Kafka brokers(K1, K2 and K3) are up cluster runs fine.
2. If K1 and K2 brokers goes down and only K3 is up then cluster runs fine.
3. If all servers are down and we up the K1 Broker, cluster stops receiving messages and consumers also gets stopped.

Please let me know if I am missing something and what if I set `transaction.state.log.min.isr=3` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

What `transaction.state.log.min.isr` does is to override the `min.insync.replicas` configuration for the transaction topic - `__transaction_state`.

Basically it controls the minimum ISR for this topic.  In the scenario you mentioned -

> If K1 and K2 brokers goes down and only K3 is up then cluster runs fine.

The cluster won't be fine and you won't be able to produce to this cluster. The producer will raise `NotEnoughReplicas` exception.
This will happen because you didn't met the configuration that you made.

For example, you are using replication factor of 3 on a topic called `mycooltopic`, and your brokers is set to `min.insync.replicas` of 2.

When producing to `mycooltopic` (with `acks=all/-1`), you will need to have at least 2 replicas that must acknowledge the write before it considered as a successful write.

Therefore, if want to change the `min.insync.replicas` to 3 - you will need to add more brokers to your cluster.

You can read more about Kafka replication in Confluent blog - [Hands-free Kafka Replication](https://www.confluent.io/blog/hands-free-kafka-replication-a-lesson-in-operational-simplicity/), and see the [official documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) (jump to `min.insync.replicas`).

Comment: "When producing to mycooltopic (with acks=all/-1), you will need to have at least 2 replicas that must acknowledge the write before it considered as a successful write." -by two replicas you mean one leader and one replica, if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 4):

transaction.state.log.min.isr is just dedicated min.insync.replicas but for the __transaction_state topic (internal topic created when you start using transactions). So it's just overriding the min.insync.replicas.

Maybe you already know, but setting the min.insync.replicas to 2 means that when your producer ( with acks=all) will produce a record for a specific topic, the corresponding broker will wait that two ISR acknowledge the write ( here the leader and one replica).

Exact same behavior with transaction.state.log.min.isr, but this will only apply to the __transaction_state internal topic

So it does make sense to set it to 2 when you have a replication factor of 3.

But, not sure to understand what you meant :

If all 3 Kafka brokers(K1, K2 and K3) are up cluster runs fine.
==> indeed

If K1 and K2 brokers goes down and only K3 is up then cluster runs fine.

==> you won't be able to produce (with acks=all or >1) new records as the replication factor won't be met.

Also, you won't be able to create new topics while producing/consuming (will get INVALID_REPLICATION_FACTOR)

Your cluster is definitely not fine

Comment: Yannick, thanks for the response, but the statement "you won't be able to produce (with acks=all or >1) new records as the replication factor won't be met", this means all the Brokers should be up and running then only we can achieve replication factor 3. But in this case how to achieve broker fail over?

Comment: I mean that if your producer use acks with value superior to 1(let's say 2), when it will send a write, at least 2 isr should acknowledge this write, but if you only have 1 broker alive ( in your scenario), at this moment, they won't be able to ack, so you'll get an error message.
But if your producer don't care about acks, it will be able to produce.
What do you mean exactly by "achieve failover" ?

Comment: Hi @Yannick, this sentence is not correct: `Maybe you already know, but setting the min.insync.replicas to 2 means that when your producer ( with acks=all) will produce a record for a specific topic, the corresponding broker will wait that two other isr acknowledge the write.`. The corresponding "leader" broker is also part of the _in-sync replicas_, so it will wait for only 1 other "follower" broker to replicate to its commit log, before acknowledging, not _two other isr_.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I had exactly this in mind but wrote something which is wrong, let me correct this